# react-native run-ios: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I use expo with Bare Workflow (and I am new with BW).
If I run my app with `expo start`, it will run perfectly. But if I run it with `react-native run-ios`  I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:38)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:429)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:428)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:108)
    in Unknown (at createStackNavigator.tsx:107)
    in StackNavigator (at App.tsx:48)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:429)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainerInner) (at App.tsx:47)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
[Fri Aug 13 2021 21:20:07.834]  ERROR    Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

I searched a solution with this same error. They all wanted i run `yarn add react-native-safe-area-context`.. so i ran it, i did `pod install`.. but nothing...
Thanks!

Comment: did u solved this?

Comment: Yes, just wrap your app with "SafeAreaProvider".